# Connection string for SqlClient/OLEDB driver like jdbc:jtds driver?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, kerberos, .net-6.0, system.data.sqlclient

I am working on .NET6 WebApi project on Ubuntu/Windows and the connection to the SQL Server DB is configured to use windows authentication. On windows I can use this connection string `Data Source=DB-Name;Initial Catalog=Cat1;Integrated Security=SSPI`. On Linux, we have ruled out using `Kerboros` for authentication and instead, we want to find a connection string similar to `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBName:Port;domain=ABC_XYZ;useNTLMv2=true` for java apps. Is this possible using SQL client, ODBC, OLEDB or any other supported clients for .net6? Using the JDBC connection string, I can connect to the desired databases in the Jetbrains Rider.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net SqlClient does not support NTLM with provided credentials, there's a tracking issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/31).  Only Kerberos, SQL Auth, and (for Azure SQL) AAD auth.

JDBC is the only Microsoft driver that supports NTLM on Linux.

Comment: I updated the question. Is this possible using any other .net6 supported clients like Oledb, ODBC ?

Comment: The jTDS driver is not a Microsoft driver.

Comment: The Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server supports NTLM in the same way.